# Temperature distribution of a cylinder if it were heated internally with a cylindrical cartridge and heated externally on its ends?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am doing an experiment in school. We are studying natural convection. Why do we use the guard heaters? Why don't we just insulate the ends? The surface of the cylinder(not including the ends) is supposed to be of uniform temperature.

[image: Heating Device and Cylinder]

Answer (score 0):

As your question suggests, the purpose of the guard heaters is to ensure that the control surface has a uniform temperature. Without them there would be a temperature gradient along the surface of the cylinder, from the middle towards the flat ends. The edges of the cylinder are exposed to less of the cartridge heater, and are adjacent to the flat ends which provide an extra  surface for heat loss. The guard heaters match the temperature in the centre of the control area, making the temperature more uniform across the control area.

Another way of minimising such *end effects* is to have a very long cylinder and use a small control area at the centre.

The use of guard heaters is better than insulated ends because no insulator is perfect, there will still be some temperature gradient towards the edges of the cylinder. They are also more flexible because the effect of the edges on the surface temperature gradient becomes greater as the difference between the core and surface temperature increases. Increasing the temperature in the guard rings compensates for this.

Comment: To solve this problem can I say that the heat entering in the axial direction and the heat leaving in the axial direction are equal and therefore the ends of the control surface can be approximated by an insulated boundary?

Comment: Yes that is another way of expressing it.